# Javascript synchronous problem

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I need to make the below function synchronous

```
function Getextents(geolist) {
    //var geolist = "10104A,10105A,10101A,10103A,10203A,10204A,10210X,10205A,10206A";
    console.log("geolist : " + geolist);
    var extent;
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction (
        '{!$RemoteAction.Arun_Map_3.getMax_info}',
        geolist,
        function(result, event) {
            getext = result;
            extent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": parseFloat(getext.min_x), "ymin": parseFloat(getext.min_y), "xmax": parseFloat(getext.max_x), "ymax": parseFloat(getext.max_y) });

            console.log("Extent_remoting : " + extent.xmin);
            return extent;
        },
        { buffer: true, escape: false, timeout: 400000 }
    )    
}
```

Function is executing asynronous.. What i missed to make function synchronous?

Comment: Client function is executing synchronously, but the AJAX request that the invokeAction sends is asynchronous by its nature. Could you describe a bit more thoroughly what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe a different approach could be used to solve your problem.

Comment: What would be the work around..??

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you are trying to do or why you need the function to run synchronously? Using Remoting it will always run asynchronously.

Comment: ... and you can do pretty much anything you want to do in the `Getextents` function a short time later in the body of your callback function when the remote call returns. That is the normal pattern in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Use can use jQuery blockUI plugin to make remoting requests appear synchronous. 
These plugins block the user actions on page till the request-responce cycle is completed.